# ReactRouter navigation in a landing page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I couldn't find a similar answer for the feature that I'm trying so I am making a new question.

I am trying to achieve navigation with react-router in a landing page. For example, I have my menu with 3 pages "Home, Projects and Contact". If I click in Projects would scroll down to the part of website where it'll be displayed my "Projects" component and not completely change the page and only display this component.

I know that in HTML/CSS pure I could set the  but how would be this with react?

Here is my App.js:

```
        <Route path="/" exact component={Main} />
        <Route path="/about" exact component={About} />
        <Route path="/projects" exact component={Projects} />
        <Route path="/contact" exact component={Contact} />
        <Route path="*" exact component={PageNotFound} />
      </Switch>
```

Menu component:

```
<header>
      <div className="container-menu container-nav">
        <div className="logo">
          <img
            className={`logo${showMenu ? " logoHidden" : null}`}
            src={logo}
            alt=""
          />
        </div>
        <nav className={`topnav${showMenu ? " responsive" : "logo"}`}>
          <ul>
            <li className="icon">
              <img
                onClick={() => {
                  display();
                }}
                src={burgerMenu}
                alt="logo"
                className="img"
              />
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/projects">Projects</a>
            </li>
            <li className="contact">
              <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what is the behavior you want? Are you describing navigation? Or smooth scroll on a single page?

Comment: Do you want to introduce 3 pages into a one single page?

Comment: this is not then a route thing but rather a scroll to a visible/non visible panel holding the component you want

Comment: You don't need to use `react-router`, because you don't want to redirect to another page.

Comment: check this package if you need smooth scroll https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but if you want to introduce 3 pages into one single page. You can check this article.
https://reactjsexample.com/hash-link-scroll-functionality-for-react-router/

You can use `react-router-hash-link`
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link

Comment: I ended up using react-scroll package but your answer lead me to that, so thank you.